# Cannot access dataLayer from Chrome Extenstion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, window, google-datalayer

I'm building a chrome extension and I'm trying to access the DataLayer, from within one of my Chrome Extension JS files.  However, I'm returned the following error:
`dataLayer undefined`

And if I try and access a specific node in the dataLayer... window.dataLayer.Test:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Test' of undefined`

If I console.log directly in console chrome dev tools, I can access the dataLayer and specific nodes within fine.

It's the first time I'm building a chrome extension...  What am I missing?

This is what I'm trying to loop through a node in the dataLayer and print it's values, in my chrome extension.  Here are key files:

**INJECT.JS - Where I am trying to access the dataLayer:**

```
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('CRO-toolBar-Container');
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function updateDataLayer() {
  var dataLayer = window.dataLayer;
  console.log('WINDOW', window.dataLayer);
  console.log('DATALAYER', dataLayer);

  if (dataLayer.Test) {
    if (dataLayer.Test.Opp) {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dataLayer.Test.Opp)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
createDiv();
updateDataLayer();
```

**BACKGROUND.JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 console.log('DOM loaded');

 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
     // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'inject.js',
    });
  })
});
```

**MANIFEST.JS**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Chrome Extension (CRO)",
  "description": "xxx",
  "version": "2.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
        {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "css": ["style.css"]
        }
    ],
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

Comment: To access variables in `window` of the page you need to do it in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm- so I gotta do something like this:

```var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    // All code is executed in a local scope.
    // For example, the following does NOT overwrite the global `alert` method
    var alert = null;
    // To overwrite a global variable, prefix `window`:
    window.alert = null;
} + ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();```

Comment: And then something like this:

```document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e) {
  var data = e.detail;
  console.log('received', data);
});```